# How to convert SAS date from 01/01/00 to 01-01-00?

Tags: date, sas, format

I am trying to change a formatted date from 01Jan2000 to 01-01-00?

I currently have been able to format it to 01/01/00 but cannot figure out how to change the / to -?

Code:
`data stocks; set sashelp.stocks; FORMAT DATE ddmmyy8.; run;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force a particular separator then use the DDMMYYx format which uses that 7th letter to indicate the separator character you want.  For a hyphen use D as replacement for the lowercase x.  So use the DDMMYYD8. format to print what you asked for.

**PS** It is not a good idea to not display the century on dates.  If you use DDMMYYD10. instead then the century is included.

**PPS** It is not a good idea to display dates in DMY or MDY order as either one will confuse half of your audience.  Try using YYMMDDD10. format instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
data stocks; 
   set sashelp.stocks; 
   FORMAT DATE ddmmyyd8.; 
run;
```